# キーボードの高さが２回目以降で縮む

Tags: swift, ios

ストリーボードに素朴に`UITextView`を置いています。

下記コードを試したところ、1回目のキーボードの高さは`print`で確認したところ`346.0`でしたが、2回目は`288.0`。

表示されたキーボードは同じ見た目ですので、高さ（`keyboardSize.height`）が変わった理由がわかりません。何故高さが変わるのでしょうか？

もしくは正しい、高さの取得方法は別にありますか？

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var hogeTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.hogeTextView.delegate = self
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else  { return }

        print(keyboardSize.height)
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        if (text == "\n") {
            hogeTextView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`のドキュメント](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621616-keyboardframebeginuserinfokey)にはこう書いてあります。

> The key for an `NSValue` object containing a `CGRect` that identifies
>   the **starting frame** rectangle of the keyboard in screen coordinates.
>   The frame rectangle reflects the current orientation of the device.

似たようなキーで、[`keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`の方](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621578-keyboardframeenduserinfokey)はこんな風:

> The key for an `NSValue` object containing a `CGRect` that identifies
>   the **ending frame** rectangle of the keyboard in screen coordinates. The
>   frame rectangle reflects the current orientation of the device.

(太字化は回答者。)

ここでの **starting frame**, **ending frame**とは、キーボードの表示/消去のアニメーションの開始時のフレーム、終了時のフレームを表していると考えられます。

iOSのキーボードは画面下部からニューっと上がってくる感じですが、画面の外にある時(`keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`用のフレームが取得される時)には、iOSはその高さには無頓着で、キーボード用のviewの高さをちゃんと設定していないのだと思われます。手元のiOS 7 Plus simulatorで試したら、1回目は0.0と表示されることが多かったです。

これからキーボードが表示される(あるいは「表示された」)と言うイベントでは、`keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`の方が、「表示されたキーボード」のフレームを表していると考えられます。次のように`userInfo`を取得する時のキーを変えてみてください。

```
guard let keyboardSize = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else  { return }
```

(ついでに、`CGRect`を保持する`NSValue`は、直接`as?`キャストでSwift側`CGRect`にブリッジ可能なので、その点もコードに反映させていますが、肝はキーが`UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`になっていることの方です。)

コードをこのように書き換えれば、常に「キーボード表示アニメーション終了時のフレーム」から高さを取得するので、デバイスの画面サイズに応じた一定の値を返すと思うのですが? お試しください。

Comment: たしかに、回答を受けて下記オープンソースを読んでみると同じように取得していますね。

https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxKeyboard/blob/c92e75bd101aa4eef929ea146e18a092e47d3a6e/Sources/RxKeyboard/RxKeyboard.swift#L56